# Titanium Appcelerator TiFilesystemFileProxy isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: appcelerator

trying to delete images that I have downloaded into the `applicationDataDirectory` from a remote server. Testing this in the simulator, I keep getting the following error.

> [ERROR] The application has crashed with an uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'.
>   [ERROR] Reason:  -[TiFilesystemFileProxy isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8dc0f34560
>
> [ERROR] Stack trace:
>
> [ERROR] 0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9101ce __exceptionPreprocess + 270

Basically I have an array of views, where each view has an imageId. When I comment out `f.deletefile()`. All of the debug strings are printed fine. However when I uncomment the `f.deletefile()` part, the app crashes with above message. The code stops at `p("typeof",typeof(views[0].imageId));`

```
p("typeof",typeof(views[0].imageId));
    if(views[0].imageId != 1) {
        var imageDir = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, '/Quotes/iphone/images/quoteimages');

        var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(imageDir.resolve() +"/"+views[0].imageId+".jpg");
        p("path", imageDir.resolve() +"/"+views[0].imageId+".jpg");
        p("file exists", f.exists());
        p("should delete img",views[0].imageId);
        if (f.exists() && f.writable && views[0].imageId != 1) {
            p("XXXXXXX");
            f.deleteFile();
        }
    }
```

I am very puzzled.
I have also tried just this:

```
var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, '/Quotes/iphone/images/quoteimages/'+views[0].imageId+'.jpg'); Same error.
```

Help much appreciated :)

Comment: Well... couldn't solve my issue, so I ended up using the tmpdirectory rather than the applicationdatadirectory. The OS takes care of deleting files in the temp directory at app close.

Comment: You can answer your own question so that other programmers can see the answer.

Comment: Its not really an answer but mire if a workaround. The problem still exists in the applicationdatadirectory. The tempdirectory is working fine as the system itself deletes that on app close.